# leaflet geoJSON filtering

Tags: ajax, filter, leaflet, geojson

I am using L.GeoJSON.AJAX to load my json.  I have the following to style the markers:

```
    var weakClusterMarkerOptions = {
      radius: 5,
      fillColor: "#FFFF00",
      color: "#000",
      weight: 2,
      opacity: 1,
      fillOpacity: 0.8
    },
    strongClusterMarkerOptions = {
      radius: 7,
      fillColor: "#CC0000",
      color: "#CC0000",
      opacity: 1,
      fillOpacity: 0.8
    };

  function customizeClusterIcon(feature, latlng) {
    if (feature.properties.strongCl === 'strong') {
      return L.circleMarker(latlng, strongClusterMarkerOptions);
    } else {
      return L.circleMarker(latlng, weakClusterMarkerOptions);
    }
  }
```

I then use the following to filter:

```
function toggleStrength(strength, showLayer) {
    jsonLayer.refilter(function (feature, layer) {
      if (strength == 'all') {
        return true;
      } else {
        if (showLayer) {
          return feature.properties.strongCl === strength;
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

The issue here is that when I filter the border of the circleMarker disappears but the marker is still visible, specifically the fill colour.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @Barbarossa see answer below

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up creating LayerGroups for each condition (weak and strong) then clearing and adding the respective groups depending on the filter.

```
toggleStrength = function (layer, showLayer, theMap) {


            switch (layer) {
                case 'weak':
                    if (showLayer) {
                        theMap.addLayer(weakGroup);
                    } else {
                        theMap.removeLayer(weakGroup);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'strong':
                    if (showLayer) {
                        theMap.addLayer(strongGroup);
                    } else {
                        theMap.removeLayer(strongGroup);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    clearAll(theMap);
                    if (showLayer) {
                        theMap.addLayer(weakGroup);
                        theMap.addLayer(strongGroup);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        };
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `fillColor` and `color` has same value `#CC0000`. Probably border is there. It's just has same color as fill.

Comment: I'm not concerned with the markers that should be there, my issue is that the markers I am trying to filter out are still there (the border, i.e color disapears but the fillcolor is still visible.

Comment: Can you show `refilter` code? Leaflet's `filter` function only applies to a new added layers. I'm pretty sure your's work the same. If so you need to use `eachFeature` and remove items conditionally.